# How to align text to right side of the container div in flex display?

Tags: html, css

can someone help me? I want to align the "End text" to the right side of the `.Container` to be horizontally in the same row with the `First name: John`.

(Recommend you when run my code to check in full screen,because you can't see well the whole container in a small window )

Check the image,this is how I want to look like:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 250px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.Container span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.dataContainer {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-grid;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.endtext {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <span>Data:</span>
  <div class="dataContainer">
    <div class="endtext">
      <p>First Name:  John</p>&nbsp;
      <p>End text</p>
    </div>
    <p>Last Name:  Williams</p>
    <p>Age:  23</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You have to tell certain children of a flex container to "grow" to fill in the remaining space. Add `flex-grow: 1` to the `.dataContainer`.

Without the grow, you can see that the red `.dataContainer` doesn't fill the parent (blue) `.Container`.

[image: without flex-grow]

After adding `flex-grow: 1` - it fills the parent as you would expect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using space between you need to make the container 100%

```
.dataContainer { width: 100%; }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 250px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.Container span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.dataContainer {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-grid;
  line-height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.endtext {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <span>Data:</span>
  <div class="dataContainer">
    <div class="endtext">
      <p>First Name:  John</p>&nbsp;
      <p>End text</p>
    </div>
    <p>Last Name:  Williams</p>
    <p>Age:  23</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not "downvote" worthy, but I caution against using width like this as the container isn't really `100%` wide. Using width like this is a carryover from tables by which you tell certain columns to "take up the most space". Flexbox has mechanisms for controlling this in a more declarative fashion.

Comment: yes, I agree, flex-grow: 1 as you suggest is a better approach, flex-grow overrides the width property too.